# How do you set the colour of the bash tab completion when `colored-completion-prefix` is turned on?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, readline, inputrc

I have `colored-completion-prefix` set on in my `~/.inputrc` file, but when I tab complete, the prefix part which has already been typed is a colour that I do not like.

In the bash manual it says:

> "**colored-completion-prefix (Off)**
> If  set  to  On,  when listing completions, readline displays the common prefix of the set of possible completions using a
> different color.  The color definitions are taken
> from the value of the LS_COLORS environment variable."

It is currently brown and underlined due to my config, which doesn't look very good. Which entry in `LS_COLORS` does it use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$LS_COLORS` is usually defined in `~/.bashrc` using the `dircolors` command and a `dir_colors` file.

I could not find any information on what entry is used by the `colored-completion-prefix` readline setting but by through the process of elimination I found that it uses `SOCK`.

I changed mine from:

```
SOCK 04;33
```

...to...

```
SOCK 01;38;5;64
```

...in my `dir_colors` file.

This will obviously also change the appearance of sockets when using the `ls` command.